# Are object Id's globally unique across an organization?

Tags: custom-object, configuration, id, object

Is it safe to say that an ID for an object in Salesforce is guaranteed to be unique across all objects for an organization? I ask this since id's for objects are prefixed with the keyPrefix value designated on the metadata for the corresponding object type.

Comment: I think they are but the key prefix are case sensitive, there could be 2 objects with keyprefix 0a2, 0A2 and both are different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they are unique. You can always copy the 18 character ID and paste in URL after like this: http://instance.salesforce.com/{ID}.  And you will go to record since they are globally unique.